# Unable to display angularjs page data after route change.

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am relatively new to angularjs and seems like I am missing something obvious here. I tried to go through documentation and tutorials, but unable to find any solution to my problem.

I have a REST service at "localhost:8080/app/rest/schools/{schoolId}/selectedindicators". I can display the results in an angularjs app page (selectedindicator.html) like so:

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="selectedindicator in selectedindicators">
    <td>{{selectedindicator.id}}</td>
    <td>{{selectedindicator.school.name}}</td>
    <td>{{selectedindicator.userId}}</td>
    <td>{{selectedindicator.dateVisit}}</td>
    <td>
        <button type="submit"
                ng-click="update(selectedindicator.id)"
                class="btn">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit
        </button>

    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Until this point everything is working fine. But, when I try to select one of the selected indicators by clicking on the Edit button I can not display the data on the Edit (selectedindicatorForm.html) page. Here is chunk of my Edit page.

```
<div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>ID</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id"
        ng-model="selectedindicator.id" required>
</div>
.
.
.
.
.
.
</div>
```

Here is my routeProvider code:

```
myApp
.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$translateProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $translateProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/selectedindicator', {
                templateUrl: 'views/selectedindicators.html',
                controller: 'SelectedIndicatorController',
                resolve:{
                    resolvedSelectedIndicator: ['SelectedIndicator', function (SelectedIndicator) {
                        return SelectedIndicator.query();
                    }]
                }
            })
            .when('/selectedindicatorForm',{
                 templateUrl: 'views/selectedindicatorForm.html',
                 controller: 'SelectedIndicatorFormController',              
            })

    }]);
```

Here is my controller code for the update method:

```
myApp.controller('SelectedIndicatorController', ['$scope', '$location', '$route','resolvedSelectedIndicator', 'SelectedIndicator',
function ($scope, $location,$route, resolvedSelectedIndicator, SelectedIndicator) {

    $scope.selectedindicators = resolvedSelectedIndicator;

    $scope.update = function (id) {
        $scope.selectedindicator = SelectedIndicator.get({id: id});
        $location.path("/selectedindicatorForm");
    }; 
}]);
```

Comment: please setup a plunk.

Comment: This video tutorial should help. Give it a try: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5uhZCc0j9RY&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

you can add a separate service (singleton object) to pass data between controllers .

looks like you `SelectedIndicator` (which is passed onto `SelectedIndicatorController`) is already doing that and you can simply re-use it .

On your `SelectedIndicatorFormController` inject this service `SelectedIndicator` and call `SelectedIndicator.get({id: id});`

Note - looks like this line `$scope.selectedindicator = SelectedIndicator.get({id: id});` inside `SelectedIndicatorController` doesn't serve any purpose.

If you could setup a plunk, I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason you're transitioning using $location.path?

The way I'd do that would be just put an  or something, with a class="btn" or some other css styling if you really want it to look like a button. With regular ngRoute, you just work with URLs, and should put all the state into the URL. I'm pretty sure setting a $scope variable and then manually changing the state doesn't actually do anything, since the new state has its own $scope.

To be perfectly frank after looking at that code, I'm going to say that you probably ought to read some angular tutorial stuff. I found egghead.io to be pretty great myself.